# How do I convert my table-based design to CSS?

Tags: html, css

im trying to learn how to use css instead of tables. i'm starting at the basics with a block of text with same height and width

```
margin-right: 60%;
margin-left:10px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom:0;
border:thin;
background-color:#FFF;
font: 9pt "trebuchet ms", arial, sans-serif;
color:#003318;
display:block;

margin-left: 60%;
margin-right:10px;
margin-top: 10px;
border:thin;
background-color:#FFF;
font: 9pt "trebuchet ms", arial, sans-serif;
color:#003318;
display:block;
```

however, the results are not good. there's no border. how can i fix this?

Comment: `border-style:solid;` ?

Comment: Though we can probably guess it, you may want to edit your code and show us a little more. What does the HTML part look like? Are these classes or IDs? etc.

Comment: You want a border? `border tr td{ border: 1px solid #000; }`

Comment: If it is tabular data - then use a table. If you are old skool and using tables for layout then use DIV/CSS. But do not abandon tables if the data should be it a table as it helps screen readers if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the shorthand border property:

`border:solid 1px black;`

Try cutting the other `border` properties and just using that and see if that does the job.

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Answer (score 0):

Tables are like structure groups of layers while divisions are simple layers. 
Think that every division is a .  The problem is how to structure your divisions.  This is where stylesheets come to your rescue.

```
ex.:
<div class="table">
   <div class="right-td">&nbsp;</div>

   <div class="left-td">&nbsp;</div>
</divd
```

And in your stylesheet

```
div.table { width:100%; float:none; margin:0px auto;}
div.right-td  { border:1px solid #000;float:rightt; width:45%; padding:6px;}
div.left-td  { border:1px solid #000;float:left; width:45%; padding:6px;}
```

This is just an example